# Strictly monotonic increasing function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Suppose that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$. Prove that $f$ is strictly monotonic increasing on $[a,b]$; that is, if $x<y$, then $f(x) < f(y)$.

***My Approach.*** Since $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$, if $a \leq x < y \leq b$, then according to Mean Value Theorem in the interval $[x,y]$ there is a point $c$ satisfying $x<c<y$ such that

$$ \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} = f'(c) > 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow f(x) < f(y)$$

But I was wondering what is the necessity of continuously differentiability. Seems that only differentiability would work too. Where wrong am I?

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me, but I wonder what is the assumption at endpoints about $f'$. If one assumes $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f'$ exists and is positive on $(a,b)$ I think your proof shows $f$ strictly increasing on $[a,b]$. Maybe the continuity of $f'$ at endpoints is used to guarantee that $f$ is continuous on the whole closed interval, and in that case continuity of $f'$ at endpoints means the relevant one-sided derivative there.