# Relationship among derivative, strictly increasing, and monotonically increasing

Tags: calculus

This very basic question is related to

[Monotonically and strictly increasing functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729586/monotonically-and-strictly-increasing-functions)

and to

[Strictly monotonic increasing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581004/strictly-monotonic-increasing-function)

but neither seems to address the exact question I have. It undoubtedly was in my textbook back in 1968, but that has long since disappeared. Nor have I found a google source that seems to be exact in its notation.

My recollection is

$f'(x) > 0 \text { if } a < x < b\implies f(x_1) < f(x_2) \text { if } a \le x_1 < x_2 \le b.$

And

$f'(x) \ge 0 \text { if } a < x < b\implies f(x_1) \le f(x_2) \text { if } a \le x_1 < x_2 \le b.$

Terminologically, I say in the first case that f(x) is strictly increasing, and, in the second, that f(x) is monotonically increasing.

Am I remembering correctly? I am particularly interested in whether I have the open and closed intervals right.

**EDIT** Based on a comment, I am editing this to add that both f(x) and f'(x) are everywhere differentiable in case that matters (as it probably does).

Comment: I think both are monotonically increasing - the first case is just **strictly** monotonically increasing. BTW, the implication goes both directions, if $f$ is differentiable over the interval $[a, b]$.

Comment: [Strictly monotonic increasing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/581004/266110)

Comment: @SahibaArora Thank you, but the question you linked to does not deal with the question of the derivative's sign being known on the open interval rather than on the closed interval. I can, however, say that both f(x) and  f'(x) are is everywhere differentiable and so continuous. I am trying to be as exact as I can be about the intervals involved.